# .NET Web Api Logging Response Body

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm Attempting to log Web Api Response Body using a DelegatingHandler.

```
    protected override System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            var response = task.Result;
            LogResponseLoggingInfo(response);
            return response;
        });
    }

    private void LogResponseLoggingInfo(HttpResponseMessage response)
    {
        string responseBody = string.Empty;

        if (response.Content != null)
        {
            responseBody = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            //WriteToLogFile(responseBody);
        }
    }
```

It works fine as long as calls to the Web Api returns a response.StatusCode equals HttpStatusCode.OK.

But any calls made that returns any other StatusCode, for example Unauthorized, results in the correct response 401 being returned correctly only on every other call.

The other times, I'm receiving a 500 response, internal server error.

Using Fiddler to look at the raw response for the 500 errors shows an HTML doc with **Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent** message.

If I comment out the **responseBody = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;** line, the correct 401 error response is successfully returned every time.

Anybody know what's causing the error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the handler to use async/await instead:

```
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,       System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        await LogResponseLoggingInfo(response);

        return response;
    }

    private async Task LogResponseLoggingInfo(HttpResponseMessage response)
    {
        string responseBody = string.Empty;

        if (response.Content != null)
        {
            responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            //WriteToLogFile(responseBody);
        }
    }
```

Stay away from using .ContinueWith and .Result as you wont be needing it if you use async/await. Here is some more info: http://www.journeyofcode.com/will-block-debunking-asyncawait-pitfalls/ and http://code.jonwagner.com/2012/09/06/best-practices-for-c-asyncawait/

Comment: I modified the handler to use the async/await code above but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: The error can be easily replicated on a new Web API project with just this handler added.

Comment: Hm, I cannot reproduce the issue. Does the code still throw exception at `await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`?